# Sphinx cannot find my python files. Says 'no module named ...'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have a question regarding the Sphinx autodoc generation. I feel that what I am trying to do should be very simple, but for some reason, it won't work.

I have a Python project of which the directory is named `slotting_tool`. This directory is located at `C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\picnic-data-shared-tools\standalone\slotting_tool`

I set up Sphinx using `sphinx-quickstart`. Then my directory structure (simplified) is as follows:

```
slotting_tool/
|_ build/
|_ source/
|___ conf.py
|___ index.rst
|_ main/
|___ run_me.py
```

Now, I set the root directory of my project to `slotting_tool` by adding the following to the `conf.py` file.

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
```

Next, I update my `index.rst` file to look like this:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. automodule:: main.run_me
   :members:
```

When trying to build my html using the `sphinx-build -b html source .\build` command, I get the following output, with the `no module named` error:

```
(base) C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\picnic-data-shared-tools\standalone\slotting_tool>sphinx-build -b html source .\build
Running Sphinx v1.8.1
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [] 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'run_me' from module 'main'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'standalone'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
generating indices... genindex
writing additional pages... search
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en) ... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in build.
```

There are no HTML pages that refer to `run_me.py` in build. I have tried setting my root directory to all different kinds of directories and I have tried replacing all dots `.` with backslashes `\` and so forth, but can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

By the way, the statement that `standalone` is not a module is in fact true, it is just a directory without an `__init__.py`. Don't know if that might have caused some trouble?

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I think your intuition is correct. Add an empty __init__.py and see if the import warning goes away.

Comment: I tried it with the `__init__.py` added, but this does not resolve the error either. Do you know of anything else that may cause this error?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I assume that run_me.py tries to import standalone but fails. I'd need to see the code.

Comment: Sphinx will attempt to import all your code, just like running it in a Python interpreter. Fix your imports or specify the path to the non-importable code with sys in conf.py.

Comment: I finally fixed the `no module named` error. Indeed, the imports require that you define the root directory in `conf.py` to such a low level, that it is at least below the - in my case - `standalone` folder. I thus set my root directory to `picnic-data-shared-tools` and each time I call to a `.py` file, I move deeper into the project structure to access it. However, generating the `html` build files, I do not get an error this time, but just an empty html. Will try to find out what is happening here, otherwise, I'll be back.

Comment: Your module must be in a Python package that Sphinx can import. You need to put the module in a folder along with an empty `__init__.py` file (thus making it a Python package), and configure that path in your `conf.py` so Sphinx can import it.

Answer (score 37):

This is the usual "canonical approach" to "getting started" applied to **the case when your source code resides in a `src` directory like `Project/src` instead of simply being inside the `Project` base directory.**

Follows these steps:

1. Create a `docs` directory in your `Project` directory (it's from this `docs` directory the commands in the following steps are executed).
2. `sphinx-quickstart` (choose separate `source` from `build`. Places `.html` and `.rst` files in different folders).
3. `sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ../src`
4. `make html`

This would yield the following structure (provided you `.py` source files reside in `Project/src`):

```
Project
|
├───docs
│   │   make.bat
│   │   Makefile
│   │
│   ├───build
│   └───source
│       │   conf.py
│       │   index.rst
│       │   modules.rst
│       │   stack.rst
│       │
│       ├───_static
│       └───_templates
└───src
        stack.py
```

In your `conf.py` you'd add (after step 2):

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', 'src')))
```

Also include in `conf.py`:

`extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon']`

And in `index.rst` you'd link `modules.rst`:

```
Welcome to Project's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules
      
   
Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Your `stack.rst` and `modules.rst` were auto-generated by `sphinx-apidoc`, no need to change them (at this point). But just so you know this is what they look like:

`stack.rst`:

```
stack module
============

.. automodule:: stack
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

`modules.rst`:

```
src
===

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   stack
```

---

---

After `make html` open `Project/docs/build/index.html` in your browser, the results:

[image]

and:

[image]

Comment: At `conf.py` the command that works for me is `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..')))` otherwise I am getting the error `WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'source'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'source'`. also you are missing `__init__.py` file at `./src/`

Comment: @YogevNeumann then you made a mistake because the example is correct. `__init__.py` was not included because `src` itself is meant to be a base directory, that's the recommended practice.

Comment: @YogevNeumann the mistake you are doing is putting an `__init__.py` inside `src`, that's not how a source layout is supposed to be used. You can put modules or packages inside `src` but it's not meant to be a package itself. That's the established practice that everyone uses, see [the docs](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/).

Comment: @bad_coder If i do that i get the error message `No module named 'src'`

Comment: @Lupos the answer works exactly as it's shown, when something doesn't work it's because you changed something relative to the answer. Do you have a `src` directory? What's the complete error message?

Comment: @bad_coder thanks for the quick replay, I made it work by not only including 'src' but also the parent folder like yogev said, so including both.

Comment: @Lupos if you've missed it I added a [link to the docs about the src layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/) in the comments. If you're using a `src` layout it's expected you know what it means in the context of the question, here's a simpler example [using a flat layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675).

Comment: this answer deserves a nobel prize

Answer (score 6):

Let's take an example with a project: [`dl4sci-school-2020` on master branch](https://github.com/aakriti0fnu/dl4sci-school-2020), ***commit: 6cbcc2c72d5dc74d2defa56bf63706fd628d9892***:

```
├── dl4sci-school-2020
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── utility
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── utils.py
```

and [utility package has a utils.py module](https://github.com/aakriti0fnu/dl4sci-school-2020/blob/master/utility/utils.py):

**Follow this process**(FYI, I'm using ***sphinx-build 3.1.2***):

1. create a `docs/` directory under you project:

```
mkdir docs
cd docs
```

2. start sphinx within `docs/`, and just pass your `project_name`, `your_name` & `version` of your choice and rest keep defaults.

```
sphinx-quickstart
```

you will get below auto-generated in your `docs/` folder

```
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       └── index.rst
```

Since, we created a separate `docs` directory so we need sphinx find
where to find build files and python src module.
So, edit the conf.py file, you can use my conf.py file too

```
import os
import sys
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..'))
sys.path.insert(0, basedir)
```

Now, to enable access to nested multiple packages & modules if any, you need to edit `index.rst` file.

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Description of my CodeBase:

   modules
```

The `modules` picks up content from `modules.rst` file which we will create below:
Make sure you're still in `doc/` to run the below command

```
sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ..
```

The output you get:

```
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── build
│   ├── make.bat
│   └── source
│       ├── _static
│       ├── _templates
│       ├── conf.py
│       ├── index.rst
│       ├── modules.rst
│       ├── src.rst
│       └── utility.rst
```

now run:

```
make html
```

Now, go and open in browser of your choice,

`file:///<absolute_path_to_your_project>/dl4sci-school-2020/docs/build/html/index.html`

***have you beautiful documentation ready***
[image: auto-generated python docs.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pvLu.jpg

***FYI, You can switch any theme of your choice, I found `sphinx_rtd_theme` and extension `sphinxcontrib.napoleon` super dope!. Thanks to their creators, so I used it.***

below does the work!

```
pip install sphinxcontrib-napoleon
pip install sphinx-rtd-theme
```

You can host your documentation it on [readthedocs](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org)
enjoy documenting your code!

Comment: **Warning to readers:** This answer is wrong and you'll me mislead if you follow it. The answer fails to use a `src` layout or a flat layout, see the docs [src layout vs flat layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/). If you want to use a `src` layout follow the top voted answer, if you want to use a flat layout see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675).

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
> ```

That's not correct. Steve Piercy's comment is not entirely on point (you don't need to add a `__init__.py` since you're using a simple module) but they're right that autodoc will try to import the module and then inspect the content.

However assuming your tree is

```
doc/conf.py
src/stack.py
```

then you're just adding the folder which contains your repository to the `sys.path` which is completely useless. What you need to do is add the `src` folder to `sys.path`, such that when sphinx tries to import `stack` it finds your module. So your line should be:

> ```
> sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../src')
> ```

(the path should be relative to `conf.py`).

Of note: since you have something which is completely synthetic and should contain no secrets, an accessible repository or a zip file of the entire thing makes it much easier to diagnose issues and provide relevant help: the less has to be inferred, the less can be wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO running `pip install --no-deps -e .` in the top project folder (or where ever `setup.py` is) to get an "editable" install is a better alternative to get your package modules on the `PYTHONPATH` than altering it in `docs/conf.py` using `sys.path`.

Comment: I have reached the same conclusion -- in fact, I would omit the `--no-deps`, since Sphinx directives like `automodule` will actually import the module using standard Python facilities, and if some dependencies are missing, you will get ImportErrors.