# Sphinx's autodoc's automodule having apparently no effect

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-apidoc

I am running Sphinx on a `rst` file containing `automodule` but it does not seem to have any effect.

Here are the details: I have a Python project with a file `agent.py` containing a class `Agent` in it. I also have a subdirectory `apidoc` with a file `agent.rst` in it (generated by `sphinx-apidoc`):

```
agent module
============

.. automodule:: agent
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

I run sphinx with `sphinx-build -b html apidoc apidoc/_build` with the project's directory as the current working directory.

To make sure the Python files are found, I've included the following in `apidoc/conf.py`:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

It runs without errors but when I open the resulting HTML file it only shows "agent module" and everything is blank. Why isn't it showing the class `Agent` and its members?

**Update**: the original problem was likely caused by the fact that I had not included `sphinx.ext.autodoc` in `conf.py`. Now that I did, though, I get warnings like:

> ```sh
> WARNING: invalid signature for automodule ('My Project.agent')
> WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting 'My Project.agent' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'agent'; the following exception was raised:
> No module named 'agent'
> ```

Comment: You module must be in a Python package. Put it in a folder which also contains an `__init__.py`, and adjust `conf.py` and your reST as needed, e.g., `mypackage.agent`.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is here, but it is not true that the module *must* be in a package. It is possible to have a single `agent.py` module and no `__init__.py`.

Comment: Indeed, that did not seem to make a difference. I've added an update to the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll try answering by putting the "canonical" approach side-by-side with your case.

The usual "getting started approach" follows these steps:

1. create a `doc` directory in your `project` directory (it's from this directory the commands in the following steps are executed).
2. `sphinx-quickstart` (choosing separate `source` from `build`).
3. `sphinx-apidoc -o ./source ..`
4. `make html`

This would yield the following structure:

```
C:\Project
|
|   agent.py
|   
|---docs
|   |   make.bat
|   |   Makefile
|   |   
|   |---build
|   |               
|   |---source
|       |   conf.py
|       |   agent.rst
|       |   index.rst
|       |   modules.rst
```

In your `conf.py` you'd add (after step 2):

```py
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..')))
```

and in `index.rst` you'd link `modules.rst`:

```
Welcome to Project's documentation!
================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   modules


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

---

---

Now compare the above with what you have - from what you shared in your question:

```
C:\Project
|
|   agent.py
|   
|---apidoc
|   |   agent.rst
|   |   conf.py
|   |
|   |-- _build
```

You ran:
`sphinx-build -b html apidoc apidoc/_build`

and in your `conf.py`:

```py
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

---

---

Your error stacktrace says it couldn't find the module `agent`. That's probably because you didn't go 1 level down in your `conf.py` (it's pointing to the path with `.rst`, not the path with `.py`), this should work:
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))`. Also, if you didn't manually edit/connect your `modules.rst` in your `index.rst` you are likely to only see that module.

---

---

You may care to notice the signatures of the sphinx commands at play:

```sh
sphinx-apidoc [OPTIONS] -o <OUTPUT_PATH> <MODULE_PATH>
```

```sh
sphinx-build [options] <sourcedir> <outputdir> [filenames …]
```

`<sourcedir>` refers to where `.rst` are, and `<MODULE_PATH>` to where `.py` are. `<OUTPUT_PATH>` to where `.rst` are placed, and `<outputdir>` to where `.html` are placed.

Please also notice, you mentioned: "the project's directory as the current working directory." I've seen "working directory" mentioned in sphinx threads on stackoverflow, interchangeably as both the `Project` base directory, or the `docs` directory. However, if you [search the Sphinx documentation for "working directory"](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/search.html?q=working%20) you'll find no mention of it.

Finally, there is an advantage to using the file/directory structure of the "getting started approach". It basically "puts you on the same page" with most threads on the Sphinx tag, and that way alleviates the mental work of mapping the cases to different directory/file structures.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful and a good reference for starting with Sphinx in general! The problem was indeed with sys.path. I was assuming it should refer to the directory from which I executed sphinx (I was doing it from my project directory) rather than from the documentation root (I still think that referring to the process working directory is a more standard approach, but ok). As for index/modules, I added master_doc = 'modules' to conf.py, so that was taken care of.

Comment: Certainly, before 'sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))' you also need 'import os' and 
'import sys', otherwise you will get an error with something like 'NameError: name 'sys' is not defined', as I did. But this is too obvious!