# Sphinx not finding classes to document

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

I am trying to genereate docs using Sphinx but I am guessing I have my path set incorrectly or something along those lines. My file structure is as follows:

```
project_name
    docs
        build
        source
            index.rst
            conf.py
    src
        classes
            book.py
            _init_.py
        app.py
```

Class book.py looks like:

```
class Book
  """ Class that describes a book.

  :param title: De pagina waarvan de review is gescraped.
  :type title: str
  :param publisher: De gebruiker die de review heeft geplaatst.
  :type publisher: str
  """
  def _init_(self):
    self._title = 'Unknown'
    self._publiser = 'Unknown'
```

The file *init*.py looks like:

```
from . import Book
```

I edited the conf.py file for Sphinx and uncommented:
import os
import sys

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../src/'))
```

And index.rst looks like:

```
.. review_scrapers documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Fri Mar 26 08:54:56 2021.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to review_scrapers's documentation!
===========================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Now when I run the following command from my project root:

```
sphinx-build -b html docs/source/ docs/build/
```

Sphinx does not seem to find the class I added to my project.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You path is correct so it's not a Sphinx issue. Unless the `__init__.py` should contain `from book import Book`. You also need an `.rst` file that actually uses the imported module, you didn't include an example of a `.rst` file or an error message. I think there is some info missing here.

Comment: @bad_coder as it's my first time using Sphinx I was not aware of the importance of index.rst. I have now added it to the question. I did not show all files as running quickstart generated quite a few. I doubt the import should change as I am able to implort the class into app.py. An error is not given when generating the docs. It just runs and outputs the HTML without the class.

Comment: OK, try adding `modules` as an entry under the `.. toctree::` (below the options). It corresponds to the `modules.rst` file sphinx-quickstart generated for you. It should work, if it doesn't edit the question to include the `classes.rst` file that should be inside the `sources` directory.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675) for how the toctree should be written in this case.