# Sphinx : How to create an own sample of documentation in Sphinx and to use it for next projects without Sphinx QuickStart

Tags: optimization, documentation, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am a beginner with a Sphinx and generally with Informatics.
I need to create a sample of a documentation for all my future documentations
(they have the same structure)
because right now I run for every new documentation QuickStart, copy old rst files and than change them.

Maybe you now how I can automate it, and run instead of Sphinx QuickStart, a function that generates my sample of documentation with rst file?
Thank yooou so much :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  If you are using a [`src` layout see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159862) or for [using a simple layout see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675).

Comment: If you are seeking a simpler solution that dispenses having to run `sphinx-quickstart` and `sphinx-apidoc` there might be one, but the initial generation step is generally considered not to be problematic (after doing it enough times you don't even have to think about it). After all, it only takes copy-pasting 2 commands to the terminal and running them. You could write a shell-script or powershell/batch-file to automate the process the added would likely not pay itself off.

Comment: Prepare the template of your projects in a Git repo, and then in the future you just clone from that repo to get started. You don't need Sphinx QuickStart afterwards.