# Placing all sphinx files in separate directory

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I want to keep all my sphinx files in their own directory `documentation/`, so that my project looks like this:

```
.
├─ documentation
│  ├─ _static/
│  ├─ _templates/
│  ├─ build/
│  ├─ index.rst
│  ├─ Makefile
│  ╰─ conf.py
╰─ source
   ╰─ main.py
```

In `documentation/Makefile` I have set the source directory:

```
SOURCEDIR = ../source
```

In `documentation/conf.py` I've added the source path:

```
import os
import sys


sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../source'))
```

I haven't changed the default values in `index.rst`.

---

My output when I build:

```
$ cd documentation
$ sphinx-build . build/

Running Sphinx v4.1.1
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build.
```

It generates `documentation/build/index.html` as you would expect, but it hasn't actually done the auto-documentation. There's nothing there:

[image: Empty Index]

My guesses are:

- I need to specify which files to document in `index.rst`
- I haven't pointed Sphinx to my source directory correctly

Comment: Try adding `.. automodule:: main` in index.rst and `extensions = ["sphinx.ext.autodoc"]` in conf.py. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html.

Comment: `SOURCEDIR = ../source` looks strange. `SOURCEDIR` refers to the directory where the .rst files are.

Comment: Put an `__init__.py` in `source` to make it a Python package. Also please show the `.rst` file that contains [autodoc directives](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#module-sphinx.ext.autodoc).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675) for a solved example of your layout.