# How to use autodoc in sphinx to show docStrings?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc, sphinx-napoleon

How to configure project so it will use Sphinx autodoc to get DocString from python code and show it on html?
Its is not clear from the documentation what to add where to make autodoc get all my docStrings.

here is my conf.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'Trying-Sphinx'
copyright = '2022, Akshat Tamrakar'
author = 'Akshat Tamrakar'

# The full version, including alpha/beta/rc tags
release = '0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.coverage",
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ['_templates']

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path.
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
# html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'


# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

And here is my index.rst

```
Welcome to Trying-Sphinx's documentation!
=========================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

.. automodule:: trying_sphinx.src
    :members:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Have you run `sphinx-apidoc` and `sphinx-build`?

Comment: @jshwi  Yes, I have but I am not getting anyting from docstrings in html.

Comment: Is there an error or warning message when running sphinx-build? Please show us what's in trying_sphinx/src.py

Comment: As an FYI, Sphinx won't build docs for private modules/functions/classes etc. Are any of them prefixed with an underscore? Also, are you using the Makefile, or running the commands manually?

Comment: See examples in [this post using a `/src` layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159862) and [this post using a normal layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675).