# Python Sphinx does not generate HTML output

Tags: python-sphinx

I am new to Sphinx, and have tried to follow the documentation and guidance from books and YouTube videos.
My classes and functions are documented like using *autodoc*:

```
class Person:
'''
This class describes a person
'''
def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.birth_date = date.today()
    self.gender = ''

def set_date_of_birth(self, year: int, month: int, day: int):
    '''
    Sets the value of the birth date.
    :param year: The year.
    :param month: The month.
    :param day: The day.
    :return: None.
    '''
    self.birth_date = date(year, month, day)
```

After launching `sphinx-quickstart` and `make html` afterwards, an `index.html` is created that only contains empty Index, Module Index, and Search Page, but no reference to the code whatever.

`conf.py` contains extensions as follows:

```
extensions = [ 'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
           'sphinx.ext.doctest',
           'sphinx.ext.intersphinx'
          ]
```

Obviously something is wrong or missing, but what? The test project does not use virtual environment, but a global interpreter instead (Python 3.10, is this of importance?).
The project itself is in PyCharm.
I would be thankful for a working and comprehensible example.

Comment: If using a [`/src` layout see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159862) or see this other answer [if using a flat layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951675).

Comment: @bad_coder Looks promising, starting my next attempt...

Comment: @bad_coder For option 1 (code files in 'src' folder): I copied everything from your sequence verbatim, an I am getting the following error:

 
L:\TestSphinx\docs\source\index.rst:9: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document ' modules'
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... L:\TestSphinx\docs\source\modules.rst: WARNING: document isn't included in any toctree

 
File modules.rst was created. What could be wrong here? TIA.

Comment: You'd better take a look at real world examples (any main stream Python package, like https://github.com/pyasn1/pyasn1) to study how they put source code and documentation together.

Comment: I see, those were warnings, and the html files do have content. The output looks though very differently from the HTML in your answers, but these, I guess, are CSS things. Anyway, something is being generated, to start with. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexKonnen You want to start simple - both the examples I linked are correct, and they can't be more concise. I advise against LexLi's example because that's way too much code and files. If an error happens with the posts I linked it's always because the user deviated from the example.