# Sphinx documentation: custom images dir and _static directory for HTML docs

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, python-packaging

I am a relative beginner developing a Python package. At the root of the repository there are two important directories: `images` and `docs`. The former contains some *png* and *svg* files I would like to put inside a documentation, the latter is where I run `sphinx-quickstart` in. I cannot change that layout therefore I have to let *Sphinx* know to use the top-level `images` directory while building the docs.

According to what I found over the internet I adjusted the `conf.py` file to have:

```py
# Add any paths that contain custom static files (such as style sheets) here,
# relative to this directory. They are copied after the builtin static files,
# so a file named "default.css" will overwrite the builtin "default.css".
html_static_path = ['_static', '../images']
```

And in the `index.rst` I have to point to the image file itself:

```
.. image:: ../images/scheme.svg
   :width: 500
   :alt: schematic
   :align: center
```

Having these two set up I run `make html` and I do get clean logs but the output directory is a little strange... Once the build is finished i have a `docs/_build/html` directory which contains `_static` and `_images` sub-directories (among many others). What I find strange is that inside `docs/_build/html/_static` I see all the contents of the root-level `images` being copied over whereas (at the same time) inside `docs/_build/html/_images` I only have `scheme.svg`. So essentially this one file is duplicated into these two subdirectories...

This does not look very clean to me... how should I adjust this setup?

---

Reply to the comment of bad_coder:
Below I will paste a tree with the dir structure (kept only the relevant elements):

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _build
│   │   └── html
│   │       ├── _images
│   │       │   └── scheme.svg
│   │       ├── _static
│   │       │   ├── scheme.svg
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── index.rst
├── images
│   ├── scheme.svg
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a file/directory tree [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159862) instead of describing the file structure in words. It makes the question much easier to read and understand.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot configure the destination, and files and directories will be copied relative to the build directory.

Comment: @bad_coder: I have adder the directory tree, updated the question.

Comment: @StevePiercy: I am fine with not having a configuration for the destination but still, something looks messed-up in this setup - I should not have the same svg file being copied into two separate places in the destination after build<?>

Comment: That might be an artifact of an earlier build. Do a `make clean`, then `make build`. Also you try removing , '../images' from `html_static_path = ['_static', '../images']`.

Comment: @StevePiercy: It was not an artifact - the setup I described above leads to the duplication of the .svg (I checked again after cleaning up). However, when I removed the additional dir from `html_static_path` I get a better outcome: the svg is available under `_build/html/_images` but not under `build/html/_static` anymore.
What is the point of this config option then... Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: `html_static_path` is used primarily for theme files (Jinja2) that reference static files. This method is actually now secondary to the preferred method of declaring extra CSS and JS in the `conf.py` via [html_css_files](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_css_files) and [html_js_files](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_js_files). It is not used when Sphinx renders reST content. Sphinx will copy files that are referenced in reST directives, for example `image`, into the build directory.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot! You want to re-write this into an answer so that I can accept?