Update Modules Index
I somehow made a mistake with quickstart when creating my sphinx project and my modules.rst file was not generated properly, as the module index is nested one level too far:
parent_directory
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

my_package

and I've now modified it to be how I intend:
my_package
=======

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

module1
module2

But when I rerun make html sphinx finds no changes.
My build is structured:

my_package

_build
_static
_templates
__init__.py
module1.py
module2.py
conf.py
modules.rst
index.rst
my_package.rst



How do I get the modules.rst changes to take effect, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Try make clean then make html.

@StevePiercy No change by using make clean - will probably end up remaking it and copying my config.

toctree creates a "TOC tree" based on *.rst files. The names of the files (with or without file extension) to include must be properly indented. See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree.

All of your files are inside the my_package directory, which is a little odd. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60159862/407651 for ideas on how to better structure the project.
